# How many combinations?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinations

How many sequences of 3 characters can be made from 100,000 characters?
The same character can appear once, twice or three times.
For instance 1,1,1 or 1,1,2 or 1,2,2.
And its the sequence that is important rather than the combination.
For instance 1,2,3 and 3,2,1 etc are legal.

Comment: @user202729 I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I didn't know about the association bonus.  I didn't mean to be rude.  If I'd realized you hadn't been here before, I would have said the same thing, but much less abruptly.  Apologies.

Comment: @user202729 Can't see the problem, the spirit of human kindness makes the world go round

Comment: @user202729 i've removed the Thank you, do i get my point back?

Comment: You don't know who downvoted anyway... --- On [math.se] it's a bit different from [so], that is, questions should show effort. (on [so] it's only for homework questions) See [Meta: What have you tried? ...](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28072).

Comment: @user202729 I normally go into the development area and they are quite hard taskmasters as well, they want to see effort

Answer (score 2):

Here's a hint.

How many two-letter words can you make from the standard "ABC" alphabet, if you can repeat letters?

The first letter has $26$ choices, and the second letter also has $26$ choices, for a total of $26^2 = 676$ total words.

Now, how many three-letter words can you make with a $100,000$-character alphabet?

Answer (score 0):

Each position has $100000$ options, and different positions are independent, so this is just $100000^3.$